# Can electron application run as a webiste if it's uploaded to server?

Tags: electron

I have customer and he says me to host the desktop application to the server i have created the application using electron and reactjs and it's working in the desktop. now to test it he saying me upload it to server. now as i know we can upload it to Azura like but accessing it like a website i don't know i said that to the customer still his trying to wrong me. can any tell me is there any possibility to do this. and he send me this as working proof but as i can see it's a web site using a Angular http://electron.abdullahbinhasan.xyz/login and he thinks it's a electron application because it's start with electron can any one tell if there is a possibility

Comment: It's definitely possible, although no idea how difficult can it be. Someone already did it with Visual Studio Code: https://github.com/cdr/code-server. After all, Electron is nothing but a modded Chrome.

Comment: ahh yes now the issues i have send him the screen record of the desktop application but he's saying that he don't need that and he send me a screen record of a webiste

Comment: Depends on what OS level functions the app is doing.  I have something similar, though in Vue.  But I built from the ground up for web, cordova, and electron. So every piece of code using device or environment specific stuff is written in such a way that it checks the environment first. This allows me to have alpha versions of mobile apps and electron apps as internal websites to be handed out.  They don't work perfect, but good enough.  For example, choose to take a picture and you get a message saying "I took a picture of whatever you imagined" and the code continues as if it worked.

Comment: Thank you for the response @Trevor now i am done building it with electron-react-boilerplate and when started he said that he needed the desktop application now he says me to upload to host to check is there any possibility to do this ?

Comment: Start a regular react project, copy your src folder in and start cleaning bugs.  That might be the easiest way.